# Unexpected Token Error in expression or statement

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell so I'll try my best to describe what i am doing.
I'm trying to run a script that will clean out my WSUS server.

this is the part of the code where it gets stuck.

$Adamj `ServerAdminProxy = $Script:WSUSAdminProxy

The error returned

At line:1 char:8
+ $Adamj ServerAdminProxy = $Script:WSUSAdminProxy
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'ServerAdminProxy' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

I though it may have had something to do with the ` to be honest I'm not sure.

Hope this is clear for you..

Answer (score 1):

> To create or display a variable name that includes spaces or special characters, enclose the variable name in braces. This directs PowerShell to interpret the characters in the variable name literally.

Ex:

```
${save`items} = "a", "b", "c"
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 0):

` is the escape character. Anything directly after it will be treated as is.
So `ServerAdminProxy is being treated as additional input or maybe a function call.

Also with the $Script:WSUSAdminProxy, the : will cause the $Script to be treated as a directory aka D:

I'm not sure how you are storing the values you want to retrieve, but you should probably stay away from special characters like ` : \ ' " in your variable names and stick to alphanumeric characters and underscore (_)